# Angular 2: Use credentials, x-domain settings

Tags: angular

Can you advise me how to set 'withCredentials=true' on my Angular 2 request?
In Angular 1 it worked fine as follows:

*x-domain settings and use-credential settings.*

```
var chat = angular.module('chat',[])
//configuration for cord
chat.config(function($httpProvider) {
//Enable cross domain calls
$httpProvider.defaults.useXDomain = true;
//allow credentials
$httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
});
```

*Function in Angular 1*

```
//http-structure
  this.structureDataRequest = function () {
  $http({
     method: 'POST',
     //graph url
     url: 'http://manny.herokuapp.com/audit/get/structure',
     header: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
  }).success(function (response) {
     dataReceived = response.content;
     buildDiagram.buildDiagramm();
  })
  };
```

*Angular 2 code to make x-domain; which needs to be modified to set `withCredentials=true`*

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable ()
    export class StructureRequestService {
    result: Object;
    constructor (private http: Http) {}
    private structureUrl = 'http://manny.herokuapp.com/audit/get/structure';  // URL to structure APi
    sendRequest() {
         let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
         let options = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers });
         return this.http.post(this.structureUrl,options)
                .map((res: Response) => res.json())
                .subscribe(res => {this.result = res;
         console.log(this.result)});
        }
    }
```

*Alternate version (still doesn't work)*

```
import { Injectable }     from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response,Headers, RequestOptions } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable }     from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable ()
export class StructureRequestService {
result: Object;
constructor (private http: Http) {}
private myUrl =  'http://manny.herokuapp.com/audit/get/structure';  // URL to structure APi
sendRequest() {
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    let options = new RequestOptions({
        headers: headers,
        withCredentials: true
    });
    return this.http.post(this.myUrl,options)
        .map((res: Response) => res.json())
        .subscribe(res => {this.result = res; console.log(this.result)});
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you can check in [Angular 2 docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptions-class.html) - RequestOptions type contains `withCredentials` field which should be set to `true` in your exapmle. Unfortunatelly I can't see `useXDomain` parameter anywhere there.

Comment: Hello Mate,like this:??
 sendRequest() {
        let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
        let options = new RequestOptions({
            headers: headers,
            withCredentials :true
        });
        
        
        return this.http.post(this.structureUrl,options)
            .map((res: Response) => res.json())
            .subscribe(res => {this.result = res; console.log(this.result)});
    }

Comment: `withCredentials` was added very recently and AFAIK is not yet included in RC.1 but will probably be with the next update. There are already other answers that show how to use `withCredentials`.